# grep for a specific pattern in a file?

Tags: shell, grep

I have a file textFile.txt

```
abc_efg@qwe.asd
abc_aer@
@avret
afd_wer_asd@qweasd.zxcasd
wqe_a@qwea.cae
qwe.caer
```

I want to grep to get specific lines :

```
abc_efg@qwe.asd
afd_wer_asd@qweasd.zxcasd
wqe_a@qwea.cae
```

That is the ones that have

```
[a-z]_[a-z]@[a-z].[a-z]
```

but the part before the `@` can have any number of "_"

So far this is what I have :

```
grep "[a-z]_[a-z]@[a-z].[a-z]" textFile.txt
```

But I got only one line as the output.

```
wqe_a@qwea.cae
```

Could I know a better way to do this ? :)

Comment: could you describe the exact rule?

Comment: you see there will be zillions of different solutions which all work on *that* data set, but produce different results on another... how are you going to accept the right answer?

Comment: Would you like to find any email that are in the form of email like `my@email.co.uk` `here22.is.my_email+home@google.com` etc?

Answer (score 1):

you can add the `_` simply inside `[a-z_]` so the new command is:

```
grep "[a-z_]@[a-z].[a-z]" textFile.txt
```

or if you want it to start with a non `_` you can have

```
grep "[a-z][a-z_]@[a-z].[a-z]" textFile.txt
```

Comment: What if the email contains number or any other valid email characters like `+`?

Answer (score 0):

The following selects lines that have at least one underline character followed by letters before the at-sign and one or more letters followed by at least one literal period after the at-sign:

```
$ grep '_[a-z]\+@[a-z]\+\.' textFile.txt
abc_efg@qwe.asd
afd_wer_asd@qweasd.zxcasd
wqe_a@qwea.cae
```

#### Notes

- An unescaped period matches *any* character.  If you want to match a literal period, it must be escaped like '.`.

  Thus, `@[a-z].[a-z]` matches an at-sign, followed by a letter, followed by anything at all, followed by a letter.
- `[a-z]` matches a single letter.  Thus `_[a-z]@` would match only if there was only one character between the underline and the at-sign.  To match one or more letters, use `[a-z]\+`.

  `@[a-z]\+\.` will match an at-sign, followed by one or more letters, followed by a literal period character.

Comment: What if the email contains number or any other valid email characters like `+`?

Comment: @Jotne Regexes exist that are fully standard-compliant but they can be [quite complex (scroll down to find one for RFC 5322)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html). The OP's goal is not entirely clear but he does not seem to be looking for a fully general email regex.

Comment: I do agree. Posted a comment to OP.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest keeping it simple by checking only one `@` is present in each line:

```
grep -E '^[^@]+@[^@]+$' file
abc_efg@qwe.asd
afd_wer_asd@qweasd.zxcasd
wqe_a@qwea.cae
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do `[a-z]` it only matches one character of that set.  That's why you are only getting `wqe_a@qwea.cae` back from your grep call because there is only one character between the `_` and the `@`.

To match more than one character, you can use `+` or `*`.  `+` means one or more of the set and `*` any number of that set.  As well, an unescaped `.` means any character.

So something like:

`grep "[a-z]\+_[a-z]\+@[a-z]\+\.[a-z]\+" textFile.txt`  would work for this.  There are shorter, less specific ways of doing this as well (that other answers have shown).

Note the escapes before the `+` signs and the `.` .

Answer (score 0):

This `regex` should get all valid email from a text file:

```
grep -E -o "\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,6}\b" file
abc_efg@qwe.asd
afd_wer_asd@qweasd.zxcasd
wqe_a@qwea.cae
```

This greps for pattern like this  `text@text.some_more_text`